# how to connect webserver on other PC in same wifi?

Tags: c#, lan, httpserver

I have Http server running on my PC, I can use localhost or 192.168.1.69 talk to the server. 
I have a tablet in the same wifi as the PC, when I do 192.168.1.69:8080/hello
I don't get any response.

I tried set up port forwarding on router, added .exe to firewall trust, also tried use public ip(that open router login page) with port number. but they doesn't help,

```
    public HttpServer(int port)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
        {
            // Requires at least a Windows XP with Service Pack 2
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "The Http Server cannot run on this operating system.");
        } // end if HttpListener is not supported

        _httpListener = new HttpListener();

        _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:" + port + "/");
        _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.1.69:" + port + "/");

        _resourceLocator = new Locator();

    } 

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!_httpListener.IsListening)
        {
            _httpListener.Start();
            _running = true;

            _connectionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ConnectionThreadStart));
            _connectionThread.Start();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Default http port is 80?

Comment: this is true but many servers will default to 8080.  My localhost has both running.